# PHP Forum - Read/Unread Posts

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, forum

After much pondering, I thought of a way to tackle this.

**Posts Table:**

`post_id` int, primary key, auto increment

`post_content` text

`has_read` text

In `has_red` would be a serialized array that looks something like this:

```
<?php

$has_read = array(
    '1' => 'true', // 1 = User ID
    '2' => 'false', // 2 = User Id
    '3' => 'false', // 3 = User Id
);

?>
```

I can't think of any issues I'd have with this, can you guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Storing a serialized array as text is almost always a sign of very bad design. You can't write queries on serialized data (easily).

Instead you should be making another table, that relates user's to the posts they've read.

Answer (score 0):

Scalability. Imagine having 133,090 users like my site does.